# IP-Cam / CCTV-Cam Live Streaming on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, rtsp

I want to get stream of an ip-cam on my iPhone/iPad and want to display it on screen. By R&D i found that ffmpeg is the only way to achieve it but i found nothing on ffmpeg. Is there any other way to achieve it or a confirmed way to get compiled ffmpeg on mac please mention that. Material regarding how to use ffmepg or source code example will be highly appreciated.

Is there nothing built-in framework to achieve it if not then please mention if there is any free framework/sdk to achieve this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: have you found anything on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually a few.

here are some links

http://www.streammore.tv/

http://www.live555.com/

I am sure if you google you can find more.

I cannot only address the first one, because that is ours, but I didn't want this to sound purely like self promotion.

Comment: is there any need of server in between app and dvr/ipcam or i can get stream directly from dvr/ipcam. can i have an example of configuration and usage of http://www.streammore.tv.

Comment: streammore play , live 555 and other frameworks can directly play rtsp streams with no need for an intermediate server. Well, that is as long as the camera is putting out a compliant rtsp feed. most ipcams can send mjpeg and rtsp, so the answer is no, No server involved.

Comment: check our github page for examples https://github.com/mooncatventures-group, streammoreplay examples are noted, a good one is avdemoPlay2l

Comment: I already downloaded all the ffplayer test ffpegdecoder but they do not get compiled not either on my simulator or on my iphone. Is this ffmpeg comilation error or something else.

Comment: they won't run on simulator, they should compile fine as long as you remove the armv7s arch in settings, we are looking at compiling for armv7s its just not a high priority right now. However all those demos have been tested on 4, 4s and 5 so if your getting an error please contact us or post it to our Facebook app group.

Comment: I will need to see a log to see whats going on

Comment: is it possible for you to contact us directly, we are on Facebook